# Function not working when called inside a div

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden form inside a `div` that is displayed on button click.

Inside the form I have an `input` text field, and a button that should call a JavaScript function that adds another input field.

If the container named `"blockOfStuff"` is a `div`, as you see it, the function doesn't work. If I change the `<div>` container tag into a `<script>` tag, then it is working...

What's wrong?

```
<script>
function addProceduri(divName){  
      c = document.getElementById("proceduri").getElementsByTagName("div").length;
          var moddiv = document.createElement('div');
          moddiv.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check" + c + "'><input type='text' name='procedura" + c + "'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(moddiv);
    }  
</script>

<input type="button" value="ADD" onClick="addbox.innerHTML=blockOfStuff.innerHTML;">
<div id="addbox"></div>

<div id="blockOfStuff" name="blockOfStuff" style="display: none;">

<form name="adaugare" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="afisare.php?add=1" method="POST">   

<div id="field"> Procedures: <input type="button" value="+" onClick="addProceduri('proceduri');">
  <div id="proceduri">  
<?php        
       echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="check0" value="1"><input type="text" name="procedura0" value=""></div>';

?>

  </div>
 </div> 

</form>
</div>  // end of "blockOfStuff" div
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `div`, and copy the `innerHTML` elsewhere, you'll have multiple elements with the same `id`. This is illegal and all sorts of weirdness happens.

Elements within a `script` tag aren't part of the "regular" document, and you don't have this conflict when they're copied.

Answer (score 0):

i've changed the onclick envent into document.getElementById('blockOfStuff').style.display= 'block' and now it's working.

Thanks